# How can I convert an amount of tokens with 6 decimals into a number with 2 decimales places using web3js

Tags: web3js

I was wondering how I can convert a specific amount of tokens, that have 6 decimals into a readable Integer with 2 decimals places. I know how to do it with tokens with 18 decimals by using the following line of code :

```
// 18 decimals token
const tokenAmountInWei = 10000000000000000000
const tokenAmount = await we3.utils.fromWei(tokenAmountInWei, "ethers");
```

How about an amount of token with 6 decimals?

Comment: Take a look at my project [evm-bn](https://github.com/paulrberg/evm-bn).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const tokenAmountwDecimals = 10000000
const numDecimals = 6 
const tokenAmount = tokenAmountwDecimals / numDecimals
```

Just divide it by the right number of decimals!  You'll have to use a bigNumber library if you have too many decimals or the number gets too big